# Не выводит результат (ассемблер)

Tags: ассемблер

Задание состоит в том чтобы написать EXE программу которая состоит в том чтобы вывести  строку потом еще раз вывести только заменив все буквы с строчных на прописные, но столкнулся с проблемой первый раз строку выводит а второй раз нет.

```
.data
 Sos db "Input string $"
 .code
 main proc
 mov ax,@data
 mov ds,ax
 mov dx,offset Sos
 mov ah,09h
 int 21h    
 mov cx,[bx + 1] 
 lst:
 mov di,cx
 cmp Sos[di+0],60h 
 jl next 
 sub Sos[di+0],20h 
 next:
 loop lst 
 mov dx, offset Sos 
 mov ah,09h
 int 21h 
 mov ax,4c00h
 int 21h

 main endp
 end main
 code ends
```

Comment: `mov cx,[bx + 1]` - что в этот момент лежит в регистре bx?

Comment: Ну на этот момент ничего

Comment: В регистре не может быть ничего. Там в любом случае что-то есть, и от этого чего-то зависит, откуда будет прочитано значение для регистра cx. В итоге у вас вообще скорее всего цикл мимо строки идет.

Comment: Это так, цикл зацикливается, а как это решить? Что нужно исправить?

Comment: Записать конкретное число в cx (индекс последнего символа строки).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так?

```
.model tiny
.data
 Sos db "Input string $"  
 len dw $-Sos
 .code
 main proc
    
 mov ax,@data
 mov ds,ax
 mov dx,offset Sos
 mov ah,09h
 int 21h    
 mov cx,len
 lst:
 mov di,cx
 cmp Sos[di+0],60h 
 jl next 
 sub Sos[di+0],20h 
 next:
 loop lst 
 mov ax,@data
 mov ds,ax
 mov dx, offset Sos 
 mov ah,09h
 int 21h 
 mov ax,4c00h
 int 21h

 main endp
 end main
 code ends
```

Comment: Ну, скомпилируйте и проверьте)

Comment: Работает, спасибо большое